# ros node to convert 16-bit color images to 8-bit?

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, image, encoding, conversion

Is there a ros node to convert 16-bit color depth images to 8-bit?

[image_proc](https://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) outputs both color and mono retain the 16-bit color.

[image_transport republish](https://wiki.ros.org/image_transport#Nodes) raw to compressed produces a format unusable by rqt_image_view- I wonder if it is handing raw bytes to a jpeg compression function that assumes they are 8-bit?  Or perhaps just the encoding string `format: "bgr16; jpeg compressed bgr8"` or `format: "bayer_rggb16; jpeg compressed "` is not usable downstream.

```
ImageView.callback_image() while trying to convert image from 'bayer_rggb16' to 'rgb8' an exception was thrown (Image is wrongly formed: step < width * byte_depth * num_channels  or  1920 != 1920 * 2 * 1)
```

or this if I debayer first:

```
ImageView.callback_image() while trying to convert image from 'bgr16' to 'rgb8' an exception was thrown (Image is wrongly formed: step < width * byte_depth * num_channels  or  5760 != 1920 * 2 * 3)
```

rqt_image_view can display my 16-bit images fine, but rviz plugins like [Camera](https://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Camera) and `Image` can't handle color 16-bit (it does support mono16 as listed on the wiki page):

```
ros_image_texture.cpp:275]: Error loading image: InvalidParametersException: Stream size does not match calculated image size in Image::loadRawData at ./OgreMain/src/OgreImage.cpp (line 318)
```

(`image_view image_view` also works with bayer 16-bit images, haven't tried on compressed)

Maybe the most expedient solution is to add 16-bit color support to rviz, though a ros node to do the conversion for other use cases would still be nice to have.

I'm okay with not having lot of control over how the values are scaled down (no advanced tone mapping)- whatever is happening within rqt_image_view looks good enough (I assume it's converting down to 8-bit before handing the image to Qt, but maybe not).  Writing a new node to do the conversion for the one image type I'm using right now isn't terrible but I was hoping to find something ready to go and supporting a multitude of formats- the next best solution would be that within rqt_image_view is a function call usable externally that does all the right things and returns a usable image, and my new node calls that and automatically will support other formats.  (I'll take a look at the rqt_image_view source unless someone else wants to first)